# Allowing is_pressed when tkinter window is not main focus

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard

Good morning,

I'm trying to make a tkinter window that will display a set of hotkeys someone can use well tabbed into a game.

However whenever they tab into the game the is_pressed function is not read and as such the hotkey doesnt work.

Below is an example of one of the hotkeys

```
 elif is_pressed("f5"):
                print("Tommy Activated")
                recolor_inactives()
                tom_label.config(fg="#86e760")
                active_img.config(image=self.tom_img)
                # ENABLE THE SCRIPT
```

Im wondering if I have to give some priority to the tkinter window or how can I get it so the script still reads keys well another window is active?

Comment: How does `is_pressed` work? That's not a built-in function of tkinter.

Comment: @BryanOakley it's using keyboard but its apart of a function that is bound to a top level window as such `self.top_level.bind_all('<Key>', active_gun) `.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard

Try this:

```
import keyboard

while True:   
    if keyboard.is_pressed('shift+k'):         
        print('shift + k is pressed')
```

Comment: This just ends up spamming what is supposed to occur in the if statement and doesnt seem to work when the window isnt the primary focus.